# Where does DNS resolution fit within the TCP/IP stack?

Tags: ip, osi

I know that it's possible to whitelist/blacklist IP addresses (for example, only allowing a few external IP addresses to be contacted from within a VPN). But since IP address destinations are the result of the recursive DNS resolution process (from what what I understand at least).

Does this mean that the DNS resolution phase of a network request is completed prior to network communication between a source and destination and therefore a completely separate process from the establishing/maintaining of a connection. Does this mean that IP/TCP is completely unaware of DNS hostname resolution?

Where does DNS resolution occur WRT the TCP/IP stack?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DNS resolution sits at the **application layer**: a host communicates over DNS to a server, which is encapsulated in (usually) UDP (the **transport layer**), which is encapsulated in an IP packet (the **internet layer**), which is typically wrapped in an ethernet frame (the **link layer**) and sent to either a local resolver or a local router for forwarding to a resolver.

But, exactly as you say, this happens before the main TCP connection.  For example in a web connection to `www.example.com`, the client will do a DNS resolution for `www.example.com` to get the IP address.

Only after it has the address, the client opens an HTTP connection (**application layer**) over TCP (**transport layer**) to the appropriate address over IP (**internet layer**) over whatever appropriate link (**link layer**).

Comment: Ah. Thank you - my mind is expanded. I did not consider that DNS resolution was in itself an application, and that as such the process utilizes the entirety of the network stack